# Найти в строке валидный JSON

Tags: python-3.x, json, строки

Есть строка, которая содержит в себе JSON и некоторое количество произвольных символов. Например:

```
my_string='2018_08_27-system {"a":"b", "c":"d"} finish {} mystring_text'
```

Ну вот такого плана. JSON может быть какой угодно длины и вложенности (зависит от ряда параметров при генерации файла), до и после него может быть что угодно, и самих подстрок, являющихся валидным JSON, может быть несколько. Проще говоря, регулярки не прокатят. Есть ли какая-то библиотека или какой-то проверенный способ, который сможет выбрать из строки все подстроки, содержащие JSON?

python3.6

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, `"2018"` — тоже валидный JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вот как-то так:

```
import json
def findjson(line):
    result = []
    open_bracket = 0
    close_bracket = len(line)-1

    while True:
        start=line.find('{', open_bracket)
        end=line.rfind('}',start,close_bracket)
        if end < start:
            if start == line.rfind('{'):
                break
            else:
                open_bracket += 1
                end = len(line) -1
        try:
            json.loads(line[start:end+1])
            result.append(line[start:end+1])
            open_bracket = end
            close_bracket = len(line)-1
        except :
            close_bracket = end
    return result


my_string='2018_08_27-system {"a":"b", "c":"d"} fin{"d":{"d":"d"}}}ish {dgd:} mystring_text {"a":"333", "c":"555"} dgf gf egggr (kljkljlk)}ff{4545} ['
for i in findjson(my_string):
    print (i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```
def getjson(istr):
    start = istr.find(' {')
    end = istr.find('} ')
    return istr[start:(end + 1)] if start > -1 and end > -1 else ''


my_string = '2018_08_27-system {"a":"b", "c":"d"} finish {} mystring_text'
print(getjson(my_string))
```

Жалко что в Python нет аналога функции языка C - "strstr".

Comment: берёт только первый

Comment: Так вам несколько надо? есть еще примеры входных данных?

Comment: ну разумеется, мне все нужно. в моём примере допустим есть ещё второй JSON, просто он пустой `{}`. мне бы все собрать в список например и потом понять какой из них содержит нужные мне данные